# Format MVC default Date (01/01/0001) to be empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, razor

my Razor form code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.achPayDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-7" })
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.achPayDate, new {@class="date"})
</div>
```

my cs code

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? achPayDate { get; set; }
```

01/01/0001 is displayed when the achPayDate=0001-01-01T00:00:00 , I want to suppress the date to be blank.  How can I do that??

Comment: Make the value `null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following

1. In your MVC Project => Views => Shared , create new folder `DisplayTemplates`
2. Create new view under `DisplayTemplates` folder and call it `Date.cshtml`

the code of **Date.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?
@if(Model!=null && Model!=DateTime.MinValue)
{
   @string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",Model)
}
```

the code of your **Model**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? achPayDate { get; set; }
```

this way will make all DateTime with data annotation `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` to follow same behavior, and also you can do the same for the `EditorTemplates`

you can get more information about `EditorTemplates` and `DisplayTemplates` [here](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)

Hope this will help you

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` has nothing to do with the template (its for generating `type="date"` when using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.achPayDate )`

Comment: in my answer  I focused on the `DisplayTemplate` and  I mentioned that  he can apply  the `EditorTemplate` also, `DataType.Date` will automatically use the `DisplayTemplate` "date.cshtml" if it was exists in the `DisplayTemplates` folder , as  long as the user didn't assign the `UIHint("...")`

Comment: `DataType.Date` will **not** _automatically use a template_. It has nothing to do with templates. Templates are selected because either the name of the template matches the model (e.g. `DateTime.cshtml`) or because of the `[UIHint]` attribute. The sole purpose of `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` is to render `type="date"` when using `EditorFor()` with the standard inbuilt template

Comment: if you defined 2 display templates ( date.cshtml and datetime.cshtml) and you used `DataType.Date` , what will happen on the view for the code  `@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.achPayDate)` ?

Comment: `DataType.Date` has nothing to do with it. Must admit I have not tested what would happen if you have 2 display templates in the same folder with the same `@model`  - will test it later :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123740/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-hadi-hassan).

Answer (score 3):

For normal DateTimes, if you don't initialize them at all then they will match DateTime.MinValue, because it is a value type rather than a reference type.

You can also use a nullable DateTime, like this:

```
DateTime? MyNullableDate;
```

Or the longer form:

```
Nullable<DateTime> MyNullableDate;
```

or use that:

```
private DateTime? _achPayDate = null;
public DateTime? achPayDate { get {return _achPayDate ; } set{_achPayDate = value;} }
```

Comment: OP's property is already nullable :) (and you cannot bind fields - they need to be properties)

Comment: I have the Web service return the DateTime.MinValue and I just wanted to suppress the 01/01/0001 date to be blank.  Can I add code on the Razor?  Thanks!  Your method return the Date too 1/1/0001--FYI.

Comment: @user6815384, Just check the value in the controller and set it to `null` if its equal to `DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 1):

I had 1900-01-01 as "Null" date and suppressed it this way:
Date.cshtml (in DisplayTemplates):

```
@model DateTime?
@if (Model != null && Model == DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00"))
{
    Html.Raw("&nbsp;");
}
@if (Model != null && Model != DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00"))
{
    @string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}",Model)
}
```

I used it in a view by its template name "Date":

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m.CarrierArrival,"Date")
```

Answer (score -1):

I added like below in web grid column

```
grid.Column("Note Date",
style: "width:159px",
format: @<text>
@if (item.NoteDate == DateTime.MinValue)
{
                    
}
else
{
  @string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item.NoteDate)
}
</text>)
```