# Blazor Serverside Application Datetime default to 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I tried to make my CreatedDate column to be null or at least show the current date when I launch the application instead of 01/01/0001. 
I tried the example in [Format MVC default Date (01/01/0001) to be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582419/format-mvc-default-date-01-01-0001-to-be-empty)
and by adding a dot notation "newPerson.StartDate.Now" to the column on the razor page which wasn't working either.

Comment: Please try to provide a little bit more context to let reader understand your question better.

Comment: <div class="col-12 row">
        <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">Start Date:</label>
        <InputDate id="StartDate" @bind-Value="newPerson.StartDate" placeholder= "Start Date" />
        &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => newPerson.StartDate)" />
    </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

In your constructor of your object:

```
MyDate = null;
```

Or if you want to use a date

```
MyDate = DateTime.Now;
```

I just tested and both work for me.

Comment: There is zero point in initializing with null, since the default is null. Also, if you do want it to default to now, specify a property default; don't initialize in the constructor, i.e.: `public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;`. Finally, don't use `DateTime.Now` in a server environment, especially.  `Now` will be server time, which is almost assuredly not the same as the end-user's time. Use `UtcNow` and convert from UTC to the appropriate timezone when displaying the date/time.

Comment: It worked! However, MyDate = null did not work for me because The table is set not to accept nuul value.

Comment: Again, don't set it to null. There's no point. If you need to enforce that it has a value, despite being nullable, use the `Required` attribute on the property.